# is there a way to remove featured image from blog page and single page

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails

```
<?php
/*
 *
 * The default template for displaying content. Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
            <div class="featured-post">
                    <?php _e( 'Featured post', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <header class="entry-header">
                     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <h1 class="entry-title">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentytwelve' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                    </h1>
                    <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
                    <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
                            <div class="comments-link">
                                    <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Replies', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
                            </div><!-- .comments-link -->
                    <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
            <div class="entry-summary">
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
            <?php else : ?>
            <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
                    <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentytwelve' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            <?php endif; ?>

            <footer class="entry-meta">
                    <?php twentytwelve_entry_meta(); ?>
                    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                    <?php if ( is_singular() && get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) && is_multi_author() ) : // If a user has filled out their description and this is a multi-author blog, show a bio on their entries. ?>
                            <div class="author-info">
                                    <div class="author-avatar">
                                            <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), apply_filters( 'twentytwelve_author_bio_avatar_size', 68 ) ); ?>
                                    </div><!-- .author-avatar -->
                                    <div class="author-description">
                                            <h2><?php printf( __( 'About %s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?></h2>
                                            <p><?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?></p>
                                            <div class="author-link">
                                                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">
                                                            <?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?>
                                                    </a>
                                            </div><!-- .author-link        -->
                                    </div><!-- .author-description -->
                            </div><!-- .author-info -->
                    <?php endif; ?>
            </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </article><!-- #post -->
```

At moment in the TwentyTwelve theme looks like `the_post_thumbnail()` gets the featured image and render it in the main blog page and the single page I tired removing it but it also removed any other images the blog might have, I would like to only remove the featured image from the main blog page where all the posts are listed and the single.php.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to modify the template files directly, you could always make use of the `post_thumbnail_html` filter:

```
function wpse70960_filter_post_thumbnail_html( $html ) {
    if ( ( is_home() || is_single() ) {
        return '';
    } else {
        return $html;
    }
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse70960_filter_get_post_thumbnail_html' );
```

This code snippet goes either in your functions.php file or in a custom (mu-) plugin.

#### Edit

From your comment:

> Im using a static page for the homepage and blog is using a new page I created in the WP CMS using a template file called Blog page. The homepage is rending the featured image for posts which is what I need. I want to avoid using the Featured image in the blog page and the singe page.

There are two approaches:

1. Don't use a custom page template to display the blog posts index. It's not necessary. Assuming that template file is `template-blog.php`, copy that file, and *rename* it as **`home.php`**. Then go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading`, and set "Page for posts" to the Page that is/was using the custom page template. That should solve the problem, and ensure that you don't lose any formatting.
2. Alternately, inside your filter callback, add the following:

   ```
   global $post;
   $page_template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
   if ( ( is_home() is_single() || 'template-blog.php' == $page_template ) {
       // etc.
   }
   ```

#### Edit 2

Full code, using alternative #2 above:

```
function wpse70960_filter_post_thumbnail_html( $html ) {
    global $post;
    $page_template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
    if ( ( is_home() || is_single() || 'template-blog.php' == $page_template ) {
        return '';
    } else {
        return $html;
    }
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse70960_filter_get_post_thumbnail_html' );
```

Comment: in this specific case, it would leave an empty link tag ...

Comment: @kaiser: re: the edit - why is `is_front_page()` necessary, when `is_home()` returns true for the blog posts index, whether the blog posts index is on the front page or on a static page?

Comment: @ChipBennett Please explain - you're our template hierarchy specialist ;)

Comment: @kaiser: **`is_front_page()`** returns true when on the *site front page*, whether the site front page displays the blog posts index or a static page. **`is_home()`** returns true on the *blog posts index*, whether the blog posts index is on the front page or a separate, static page. So, when the blog posts index is on the front page, *both* `is_front_page()` and `is_home()` will return true; otherwise, one or the other, but not both, will return true. I think `is_home()` covers the OP's use case.

Comment: This function is great, but it also removes any featured images I have on my home page.. I tried removing the `is_home() ||` but that didnt seem to do anything. How would I modify this function so it only works on the blog and `single.php` page?

Comment: I don't understand your question. **`is_home()`** *is* the blog. Can you perhaps clarify your question?

Comment: Im using a static page for the homepage and blog is using a new page I created in the WP CMS using a template file called Blog page.

The homepage is rending the featured image for posts which is what I need.

I want to avoid using the Featured image in the blog page and the singe page.

Comment: Thanks for that; I think it explains what's going on. The problem is that you're using a custom page template for the blog posts index. See updated answer.

Comment: Sorry quite novice at php trying to use your second approach, using the function method like this, `global $post;
$page_template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
function wpse70960_filter_post_thumbnail_html( $html ) {
    if ( ( is_home() is_single() || 'template-blog.php' == $page_template ) {
        return '';
    } else {
        return $html;
    }
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse70960_filter_get_post_thumbnail_html' );` seems to be coming back with errors

Comment: See edited/updated answer. That needs to be *inside* your callback, not *before* it.

Comment: seems to be breaking still, not quite sure where the bug is...sorry to be such a pain.

Comment: Perhaps try the method of using Settings -> Reading to choose the page for posts, rather than the custom page template?

Comment: I've made the settings >reading to Blog page using a default template, and using this function `function wpse70960_filter_post_thumbnail_html( $html ) {
    if ( ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) || is_single() ) {
        return '';
    } else {
        return $html;
    }
}
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse70960_filter_get_post_thumbnail_html' );` doesnt render the featured image on the home page.

Comment: Yes, because you're *telling* it not to, with the `is_front_page()` in the conditional. That's why I didn't want it there, @kaiser ;)

Comment: removing the `is_front_page()` doesnt seem to be doing it either :(

Comment: Can you post a live link? Also: what are your settings for `page_on_front` and `page_for_posts`?

Comment: I'm using a static page for home which uses a template, the home page static page has a featured image and the template has the  `<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1&tag=home_hotlist'); ?>              
              <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>` loop thats gets a post with a feature image, I cant really post a live link since I dont have it up anywhere at the moment only local development

Comment: Please add follow up stuff to the question or take this to chat. Comments are not meant for extended discussion.

Comment: Grundizer that's not what I asked. @rarst, I disagree that this constitutes "extended discussion", but even so, comments *are* getting too lengthy. Maybe someone can help him in chat? I'll be offline for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap this inside an `if` statement:

```
<?php
if ( ( is_home() OR is_front_page() ) OR is_single() )
{
    ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a><?php
}
?>
```